# Angular 4 ControlValueAccessor value on submit and value changes events

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, controls, onchange

Inside my Angular (4 + Typescript) project I used already prepared component (it doesn't really matter which since the way of extending ControlValueAccessor is same, but if this matters I used ng2-select) which I wanted because of better UX and nicer look. After including it to my form component which is using reactive forms I saw, that on submit I get back (for the form control) object based on class SelectItem which is used inside prepared component, to manage selected item(s) - like this:

```
// console.log(this.myForm.values)
Object {
    txtInput: 'value',
    // ...
    preparedComponent: SelectItem { // <--
        id: '1',
        text: 'Chosen item'
    }
}
```

Since the component is basically just a replacement for standard select control, I was expecting that I'll get back an ID of chosen item formed as string - like this:

```
// console.log(this.myForm.values)
Object {
    txtInput: 'value',
    // ...
    preparedComponent: '1' // <--
}
```

After I learned what actually ControlValueAccessor is and how it works, I changed the way of what comes back on submit (or better to say on item change - `onChange`) to the ID of an item. The problem was solved for some time until I started setting predefined values (on editing instance) to form controls instead of empty values (on adding instance). I figured out that this time the `writeValue` is assigning values to form control based on what it is sent to it as predefined value. So in case that I sent predefined value as ...

```
Object {
    id: '1',
    text: 'Chosen item'
}
```

... this was also the value in Object on submit just as in the first code example above. I made a workaround for this, to assign correct value to control with `onChange` right after the `writeValue` is called. This was really improper way of doing it, but I couldn't figured out anything other than that:

```
public writeValue(val: any): void {
    this.selectedItems = val; // val is for example Object { id: '1', text: 'Chosen item' }

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.onChange(val.id); // just an example of emitted value, there should be some checks val is object and id exists in real code
    }, 0);
}
```

And that also worked as far as I didn't start with subscribe to form control's `valueChanges`. The problem is that with each assigning of predefined value to prepared component, there is also an emit of the value used after submit, back to subscribers even when using `{ emitEvent: false }`.

So this are the things I want to have handled with prepared component somehow, since I want to get right value from control on submit and I don't want emit change to subscribers until the value is really not changed, not just replaced as predefined value. Any idea how to handle this will be appreciated.

Comment: I kinda went through this exact process. I'm not exactly sure I understand the exact problem you're having.

Comment: The problem is mainly with `onChanges` inside `writeValue`. Firstly because the `setTimeout` which is really the last thing I'd do as a workaround and secondly because it emits change event when initialized with predefined value. Ideally input and output values would be separated - Input would accept object and Output would return ID of selected object. Therefore is no need for change emitting on value init, because this is not what one would expect as default behaviour (in case of `{ emitEvent: false }` on `setValue` of control or form `reset` Angular doesn't emit event when chaning value).

Comment: I'm pretty confident this is more of an issue because you're (and I have too) "fighting" ng2-select (which is barely maintained btw)

Comment: Can you create a plunker?

Comment: You should try cutting down the question, it's really difficult to understand what the actual question is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understood this correctly, but I'd like to give it a shot.

You want the component's *input* to be of the following type:

```
{
    id: string,
    text: string
}
```

But you want the component's *output* to be just the string ID of the selected item.

I would argue that this data flow is a bit awkward. During initialization, `preparedComponent` is an `object`, but when an item is selected you want to turn it into a `string`. Aside from the issue of type safety, it just feels unintuitive.

For comparison, imagine doing this with `ngModel` and a text input:

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="preparedComponent" />
```

Would you expect to pass in an object, and get back a string when the user types? Probably not.

---

But let's assume that it must be like this for some reason. You proceeded by either modifying `ng2-select`'s  implementation of `ControlValueAccessor`, or creating your own component which implements `ControlValueAccessor` and wraps `ng2-select`. (I can't tell which of these you were doing in your question). Now you call `this.onChange(val.id)` when an item is selected, which updates the parent component with the string ID.

Then you noticed a separate issue, which is that `ng2-select` fires a change event during initialization if you predefine a selected value. This is odd because the user did not interact with the select control yet. So you tried initializing `preparedComponent` by calling `setValue` on your form control with `emitEvent: false`, but I am guessing this didn't work because while it may have prevented a change event from being emitted when you initialized your data, `ng2-select` made the second change to your data immediately.

So instead, you worked around this by waiting until the first update by `ng2-select` updates the parent component to a new  object, and then (using `setTimeout`) you overwrite it with the string ID you actually want. This keeps `preparedComponent`up to date with a string, but does not solve the issue of the change event firing even when the user did not interact with the control. (By the way, if you are wrapping `ng2-select` with your own component then I'm not sure why you'd have to do this `setTimeout` part, because wouldn't you already have another function which calls `this.onChange(val.id)` when `ng2-select` informs you of a new selected item, as I mentioned in the previous paragraph?)

---

Since I can't tell whether you are modifying `ng2-select` directly, or wrapping it with your own component:

If you are modifying `ng2-select`, why not just find its `writeValue` method and remove the code that emits an event? This way it updates the DOM when you predefine a value, but doesn't then overwrite your value.

If you are wrapping `ng2-select` with your own component, why not just modify your `writeValue` method to store a flag if `ng2-select` is about to fire an event, so you can ignore it:

```
private: ignoreSelectedEvent = false;

public writeValue(val: any): void {
    this.ignoreSelectedEvent = true;

    // Update ng2-select, which will cause an event to fire
}
```

And then in your function that reacts to a new selected item:

```
if (this.ignoreSelectedEvent) {
    this.ignoreSelectedEvent = false;

    return;
}

// Update the model with the string ID

this.onChange(val.id);
```

Comment: I totally second this opinion. The biggest downside of using different value types on input and output is the moment when your form is still pristine. Without user changes made yet, your code would probably expect `form.value` to have the output type, but you have just barely initialized the form, so why would it? And the keyword here is **expect** => what would one write in unit tests? `expect(form.value).to...`?

Answer (score 0):

Basically the question was asking if it's possible to send different value types to a control component as initial value which is handled by writeValue method. This one should then convert the value into string ID or array of string IDs, depending on which type is selected - single value or multiple values. As Frank said in his answer, is a bit awkward to do this and to call onChange with setTimeout workaround.

So the solution is to set initial value to what would the control component return in onChange after converting some object to ID/array of IDs. The component itself must choose appropriate object from all available items depending on the ID/IDs which are sent into it.